# how to solve error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')' in unity 3d game engine

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

using UnityEngine;

public class playermove : MonoBehaviour{
public float moveSpeed=5f;

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update(){
    jump();
   Vector3 movment = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"),0f ,0f);
   transform.position += movment * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed; 
}
void jump() {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("jump"))
    gameObject.GetComponent<"RigidBody2D">();AddForce(new Vector2(0f,5f),ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

}

i have this code i am getting error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'
problem.

Comment: So it seems like you are using a bad IDE to manage the code. The IDE should point out that the semi colon you are using is incorrect. I recommend brushing up on C# and also the Unity API, since, using a string inside of < and > characters is not valid for C#, much less Unity. These are basic C# issues here.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("jump")) {
gameObject.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f,5f),ForceMode2D.Impulse)
}
```

No need for the quote on GetComponent! And also ";" is used to end a line, use "." in your case.